# Show submenus from database in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, submenu

I have a menu bar in html with css. One menu is Country. When mouse hovers to menu'Country' I want show all county names from database.

```
<li><a href="#">Country</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="">UAE</a></li>
       <li><a href="">India</a></li>
       <li><a href="">USA</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I manually type this(UAE,India,USA). I need to load the list from database

Comment: ".I need to load the list from database" - what's stopping you?

Comment: not able to bind with menu

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link, its has a good example of a menu with sub-menu

This is just the pure css and html, since I'm not a Visual basic person I cant provide you with that part of the code.

[Here](http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd)

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Country</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">UAE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Excellent example. Just use `<asp:hyperlink ID="hyper1">` instead of `<a href="#">UAE</a>` and so on. Use ID of hyperlink in Code Behind to set the data retrieved from Database using `NavigateURL` property.